# How many sets $A \subset [1,2,...,100]$ of size $20$ satisfy $|a_1 - a_2|\geq 2$ for distinct $a_1, a_2 \in A$

Tags: combinatorics

I've got the next interval: $[1,2,...,100]$. How many sets of $20$ the subtraction between each two numbers in the set is at least $2$?

I've got a starting idea simplifying the question [Might be incorrect]:

We'll look at the question this way, I've got a set of $20$ cells with $19$ partition between them and $n$ amount of balls. [We'll look at $n$ soon enough]. The cells will represent the numbers $1,2,\ldots,20$ and the partitions will represent the 'space' between the numbers. [This means, I'll add the partition to the right cell]. For the first number of the set we'll add a partition grouping up with $1$ [Though, it won't be a part of the set].

So, given that idea, and since the minimum amount of subtraction between two cells is $2$, I'll insert $1$ ball into each partition [total number of $19$ balls].

Summary: Say, we have $1,3,5,7, \ldots, 39$, means it looks like: $$1||1|o|2|o|3|o|5|...|o|20$$

Looking at $n$, it's maxed by $80$ [Since if I'll add up $80$ to $20$, it'll be $100$], and since I already used $19$, I'm left with $61$ balls. So, the number of possible options is just like looking at an equation like this:

$$x_1+x_2+x_3+\ldots+x_{20}=k,$$ where $x_1,x_2, \ldots$ represents the partitions looking from left to right, and $k$ represents the number of balls left.

So I get the sum of $\binom{20+k-1}{20-1}$ from $k=0$ to $k=61$.

Am I right or am I missing something?

Comment: Don't use "group" instead of "set". Groups are way other thing in mathematics.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The basic idea is OK, but adding two balls between numbers forces them to have distance $\gt2$, not $\ge2$. So you only want one fixed ball between any two numbers. That leaves $100-20-19=61$ balls, which can be distributed arbitrarily over $21$ different slots.

I'm not sure I understand the second part of your approach; as far as I understand it it looks wrong. Using the [stars and bars](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_%28combinatorics%29) approach, the number of ways to distribute $61$ balls over $21$ slots is found to be $\displaystyle\binom{61+21-1}{61}=\binom{81}{61}$.

Comment: How is your approach taking into account a groups like: [1,4,6,8,10...,40]?
Means: Adding only 1 ball [beyond the minimum needed] to a certain partition?

Comment: And your first part is right, I did it wrong [Not taking into account the numbers i mark already have 'spacing' of 1.

Comment: @TheAlchemist: I'm afraid I don't understand the question. Why do you think that's not being taken into account? There's $1$ additional ball between $1$ and $4$ and the remaining $60$ balls are to the right of $40$; that's one way of distributing $61$ balls over the $21$ slots.

Comment: Additional ball between 1 and 4, And leave the rest as 2. Means there are a sum of 20 balls used, Not 80. And it still fits the question.

Comment: @TheAlchemist: That appears to be a misunderstanding of my approach. There are $21$ slots, $19$ between the numbers, $1$ to the left and $1$ to the right. In your example, there are $60$ balls in the slot to the right. Now I think I understand where you got the incorrect expressions in the second part of the question; it seems you were using $19$ slots instead of $21$?

Comment: Let me see if i get you now: There are 21 slots, 19 common between the numbers. The one to the left will help me with adding the different combination to the first number, And the one to the right will be 'The Leftovers'. Having that in mind you first of all put 1 ball in the slots between the numbers [Making sure the term is right]. And then using the stars and bars approach you get all the possible combinations?

Comment: @TheAlchemist: I'm not sure I follow what you mean by "adding the different combination to the first number" and "The Leftovers"; I don't see any asymmetry between left and right, and your formulations sound to me as if you do see one; but other than that I think you've described roughly what I meant.

Comment: I'm trying to 'picture' how's the solution works. why did you add the extra two slots to the right and left? what is their meaning?

Comment: @TheAlchemist: You have $100$ numbers and you're choosing $20$ of them. So there are $100$ fields, of which $20$ are to be filled with a number and $80$ with a ball. Each of the balls can be either to the left of the first number, in one of the $19$ spaces between numbers, or to the right of the last number. If you omit the left and right slots, all the balls have to be between the numbers, so the first number is forced to be $1$ and the last number is forced to be $100$. I suggest that you read the Wikipedia article I linked to in the answer; that should hopefully make things clearer.

Comment: I got it, Thanks you very much.

Answer (score 1):

I would just like to note that using a start-and-bars like approach is really not necessary. The requirement that no two adjacent numbers can be chosen means that every chosen number must be followed by a non-chosen number, except for the very last chosen number where this is not required. So you can treat each of the first $19$ chosen numbers together with the following un-chosen number as a single unbreakable chosen unit (the final chosen number forms a chosen unit in its own). This pairing up effectively reduces the number of elements by $19$, so the problem is equivalent to choosing $20$ elements in a list of $100-19=81$. You could similarly handle any minimum distance requirement: if $k$ elements out of $n$ have to be chosen with minimal distance$~d$ between them, there will be $\binom{n-(k-1)(d-1)}k$ possibilities.